# Virt-Manager (QEMU/KVM) install internal error when using UEFI x86_64 OVMF firmware

Tags: 18.04, uefi, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

## EDIT

> I've summarized the issue and the actual fix for others to see just the highlights of my original post.

#### The "internal error" issue when using the OVMF firmware

The following error occurs when you use an `arm64` EFI firmware on an `x86`-based ROMs (see **@Christian Ehrhardt**'s answer) which I mistakenly did before when I was testing out UEFI firmwares with Kubuntu 18.04.3 LTS VM in Virt-Manager:

[image: virt-manager-internal-error]

> Basically, you can get the `x86_64` EFI firmware with the `ovmf`
>   package:
>
> ```
> $ apt install ovmf
> ```
>
> And the `arm64` EFI firmware with the `qemu-efi` package:
>
> ```
> $ apt install qemu-efi
> ```

#### The fix I did was very simple

Tracing the error's full deatils log:

```
Unable to complete install: 'internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: 2019-11-11T22:17:50.165625Z qemu-system-x86_64: -drive file=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/nvram/kubuntu-18.04.3-lts_VARS.fd,if=pflash,format=raw,unit=1: oversized backing file, pflash segments cannot be mapped under 00000000ff800000'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 89, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/create.py", line 2553, in _do_async_install
    guest.start_install(meter=meter)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/guest.py", line 498, in start_install
    doboot, transient)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/guest.py", line 434, in _create_guest
    domain = self.conn.createXML(install_xml or final_xml, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 3603, in createXML
    if ret is None:raise libvirtError('virDomainCreateXML() failed', conn=self)
libvirtError: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: 2019-11-11T22:17:50.165625Z qemu-system-x86_64: -drive file=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/nvram/kubuntu-18.04.3-lts_VARS.fd,if=pflash,format=raw,unit=1: oversized backing file, pflash segments cannot be mapped under 00000000ff800000
```

It is complaining about the guest VM's VARS (`.../kubuntu-18.04.3-lts_VARS.fd`):

```
libvirtError: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: 2019-11-11T22:17:50.165625Z qemu-system-x86_64: -drive file=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/nvram/kubuntu-18.04.3-lts_VARS.fd,if=pflash,format=raw,unit=1: oversized backing file, pflash segments cannot be mapped under 00000000ff800000
```

Notice that the issue will not occur on other VMs you create with a different name. To fix this, simply delete the VARS file so you could re-create the VM with the same name:

```
$ rm /var/lib/libvirt/qemu/nvram/kubuntu-18.04.3-lts_VARS.fd
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all (you did already, but others finding this might wonder as it isn't auto-installed as dependency in 18.04 - it is on later releases) you need to install `ovmf`

```
$ apt install ovmf
```

I tried the same on 18.04 and 20.04 and both worked fine.
Note: A common reason for this error is to use arm64 EFI roms on x86 ([example 1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/virt-manager/+bug/1637693), [example 2](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=860363), but your config LGTM (we can see the x86 in the path).

Finally I saw that your system is complaining about your VARS file `.../kubuntu-18.04.3-lts_VARS.fd` and not the actual rom which ends in `CODE.fd`.

When I create such a guest in virt-manager the XML it creates looks like:

```
<loader readonly='yes' type='pflash'>/usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_CODE.fd</loader>
<nvram>/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/nvram/ubuntu18.04_VARS.fd</nvram>
```

The latter was auto-created and usually is a copy from `/usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_VARS.fd`. The error you mention would occur if these file sizes are off (8MB max, 128KB is the usual size).

Here how they'd look on a normal system:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root         root 128K Jul  8 16:07 /usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_VARS.fd
-rw------- 1 libvirt-qemu kvm  128K Nov 12 08:05 /var/lib/libvirt/qemu/nvram/ubuntu18.04_VARS.fd
```

Most likely this copy from the empty template went wrong, or your base copy is broken/oversized. Could you please check this?

Comment: Thanks for your answer sir! When I was testing before, I accidentally used the UEFI `aarch64` AAVMF firmware from the package `qemu-efi`, and after that, it got errors with OVMF firmware too. I don't know the workaround for the issue, but I got it working now. See my edited answer :)

Comment: Ok, it is indeed the VARS under the name: `/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/nvram/kubuntu-18.04.3-lts_VARS.fd`. I've deleted it and re-create the VM with the same name which is `kubuntu-18.04.3-lts` it is all working now. Thank you once again (wish I could double upvote).